# DatePicker to text on navigated in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, datepicker

I am trying to convert the date format to text but as it said it doesn't have that Text extension. How do I solve this part? Below are my codes

```
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Date"))
        {
            dateData.Text = NavigationContext.QueryString["Date"].ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if dateData is a datepicker control then DatePicker Has a 'Value' property you can not assign a 'Text' property to it.

Ty setting it like this:

```
dateData.Value=your value;
```

Comment: I did it in this way. dateData.Value = DateTime.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["Date"]); Thanks so much for the help! it works now